# "Maximum recursion depth exceeded" when using lru_cache

Tags: python-3.x, caching, recursion

I wanted to calculate a recursive function using lru_cache. Here is a simplified version of it:

```
from functools import lru_cache

@lru_cache(maxsize=None)
def f(n:int)->int:
    if (n==0): return 1
    return n+f(n-1)

### MAIN ###
print(f(1000))
```

It works well when I run f(100), but with f(1000) I get:

```
RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded in comparison
```

One solution is to calculate a table of values for f myself. Is there a solution that does not require me to manually create a table of values?

Comment: this has nothing to do with `lru_cache`. Python simply limits recursion to a depth of 1000 by default.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the maximum recursion depth in Python, and how to increase it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3323001/what-is-the-maximum-recursion-depth-in-python-and-how-to-increase-it)

Comment: @hop this is not a duplicate. See the answer below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that you *can* use your function as-is, but you need to ensure each fresh call doesn't have to recurse more than several hundred levels before it hits a cached value or recursive base case; e.g.,

```
>>> f(400)
80201
>>> f(800)  # will stop recursing at 400
320401
>>> f(1000) # will stop recursing at 800
500501
```

I've resorted to that at times ;-)  More generally, you could write a wrapper function that repeatedly tries `f(n)`, catches `RecursionError`, and backs off to calling it with ever-smaller values of `n`.  For example,

```
def superf(n, step=400):
    pending = []
    while True:
        pending.append(n)
        try:
            f(n)
            break
        except RecursionError:
            n = max(n - step, 0)
    while pending:
        x = f(pending.pop())
    return x
```

Then

```
>>> superf(100000)
5000050001
```

Comment: @hop, I doubt anyone is joking ;-)  The OP appears to be a doctoral candidate trying lots of ideas.  Recursive functions are often very natural in research, and `@lru_cache` can speed them enormously.  When they work out well for small cases, you want to push to larger & larger cases.  In my experience, most ideas eventually fizzle out.  The goal is to write the least code necessary to evaluate an idea "fast enough", and every by-hand code optimization of an obvious recursive function risks introducing errors.

Comment: @TimPeters: I'm not going up against _you_, but nothing was learned here today.